Python playwright._impl._errors.Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation
I am running playwright python in sync mode, and I have a popup window. Inside the popup window, when I click a button called 'Add to List', I get following exception:
playwright._impl._errors.Error: Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation
Any help would be greatly appreciate it. I have been trying to troubleshoot this issue for more than a week and I even tried putting breakpoints etc but the debugger crashes.
The exception happens at this point in code where I am using javascript to click the button using xpath:
parent.evaluate('''(xpath) => {
const element = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue; if (element) element.click();}''', xpath)
Before this I tried in python as follows:
parent.locator(xpath).click()
but that doesn't help either.
The above function works fine for other buttons in the popup window but eventually I run into issues on this one button 'Add to List', which like any other button, in web page the button looks like this:

The entire stack trace of the exception looks like this:
Exception in callback SyncBase._sync..(<Task finishe... navigation')>) at C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_sync_base.py:109
handle: <Handle SyncBase._sync..(<Task finishe... navigation')>) at C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_sync_base.py:109>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\events.py", line 84, in _run
self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_sync_base.py", line 109, in 
task.add_done_callback(lambda _: g_self.switch())
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_connection.py", line 428, in _listener_with_error_handler_attached
potential_future = listener(params)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_browser_context.py", line 122, in 
"page", lambda params: self._on_page(from_channel(params["page"]))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_browser_context.py", line 214, in _on_page
page._opener.emit(Page.Events.Popup, page)
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyee\base.py", line 208, in emit
handled = self._call_handlers(event, args, kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyee\base.py", line 184, in _call_handlers
self._emit_run(f, args, kwargs)
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyee\asyncio.py", line 53, in _emit_run
self.emit("error", exc)
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyee\base.py", line 211, in emit
self._emit_handle_potential_error(event, args[0] if args else None)
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyee\base.py", line 169, in _emit_handle_potential_error
raise error
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\pyee\asyncio.py", line 51, in _emit_run
coro: Any = f(args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_impl_to_api_mapping.py", line 123, in wrapper_func
return handler(
^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\newcodeCCSample9.py", line 167, in handle_popup2
retry_interaction(popup, f"Click Add to List Button", '//[@id="_ctl0_contentPlaceHolder_btnAdd"]', 1, False, True)
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5\newcodeCCSample9.py", line 86, in retry_interaction
parent.evaluate('''(xpath) => {
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright\sync_api_generated.py", line 8138, in evaluate
self._sync(
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_sync_base.py", line 113, in _sync
return task.result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_page.py", line 416, in evaluate
return await self._main_frame.evaluate(expression, arg)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_frame.py", line 278, in evaluate
await self._channel.send(
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_connection.py", line 59, in send
return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_connection.py", line 509, in wrap_api_call
return await cb()
^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\LDulepe\PycharmProjects\pythonProject5.venv\Lib\site-packages\playwright_impl_connection.py", line 97, in inner_send
result = next(iter(done)).result()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
I am seeking for any alternative ways to click the button besides the javascript evaluate() or locator..click(). I have also tried putting timeout etc, just run out of options. I have also reviewed all suggestions before posting this question, noticed that a few suggestions were either related to playwright JS or playwright async. Any other suggestions, what I can do?

Please share a [mcve] of the code that can be run to reproduce the error.
